# How can get time interval data from org.json.JSONArray in java?

Tags: java, arrays

**I have below data:**

```
[{
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:20:00",
    "High": 1432.15,
    "Open": 1425.8
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:25:00",
    "High": 1425,
    "Open": 1424
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:30:00",
    "High": 1423.1,
    "Open": 1423.1
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:35:00",
    "High": 1421.1,
    "Open": 1419.15
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:40:00",
    "High": 1420.85,
    "Open": 1418.7
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:45:00",
    "High": 1418.9,
    "Open": 1415.85
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:50:00",
    "High": 1418.9,
    "Open": 1418.5
}]
```

**but I want data like:**

for 10 minutes interval :

```
[{
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:20:00",
    "High": 1432.15,
    "Open": 1425.8
},  {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:30:00",
    "High": 1423.1,
    "Open": 1423.1
},  {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:40:00",
    "High": 1420.85,
    "Open": 1418.7
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:50:00",
    "High": 1418.9,
    "Open": 1418.5
}]
```

**for 15 minutes interval**

```
[{
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:20:00",
    "High": 1432.15,
    "Open": 1425.8
},{
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:35:00",
    "High": 1421.1,
    "Open": 1419.15
}, {
    "DT": "2020-12-18 09:50:00",
    "High": 1418.9,
    "Open": 1418.5
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java 8 and above**

Create the methods below and call `JSONArray tenMinutesArray = filterData( originalJSONArray, 10 );`

```
private static JSONArray filterData( JSONArray values, int interval ) {
    JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray();
    newArray.put( values.getJSONObject( 0 ) );
    LocalDateTime start = parseDate( values.getJSONObject( 0 ).getString( "DT" ) );

    for ( int i = 1; i < values.length(); i++ ) {
        JSONObject entry = values.getJSONObject( i );
        LocalDateTime dt = parseDate( entry.getString( "DT" ) );
        int diff = dt.minusMinutes( start.getMinute() ).getMinute();
        if ( diff % interval == 0 ) {
            newArray.put( entry );
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

private static LocalDateTime parseDate( String dateTime ) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse( dateTime.replaceAll( " ", "T" ) );
}
```

**Java 7 and older**

This is easiest done with [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Add the dependency to your `<dependencies>` node in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Copy the methods below and call `JSONArray tenMinutesArray = filterData( originalJSONArray, 10 );` with the amount of minutes you want to set as an interval.

```
private static JSONArray filterData( JSONArray values, int interval ) {
    JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray();
    DateTime start = parseDate( values.getJSONObject( 0 ).getString( "DT" ) );
    newArray.put( values.getJSONObject( 0 ) );

    for ( int i = 1; i < values.length(); i++ ) {
        JSONObject entry = values.getJSONObject( i );
        DateTime dt = parseDate( entry.getString( "DT" ) );
        Minutes diff = Minutes.minutesBetween( start, dt );
        if ( diff.getMinutes() % interval == 0 ) {
            newArray.put( entry );
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

private static DateTime parseDate( String dateTime ) {
    return DateTime.parse( ( dateTime + "Z" ).replaceAll( " 0?", "T" ) );
}
```

Comment: The Joda-Time project itself [recommends](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) using `java.time` instead: _"Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project."_ Can `java.time` be used here, instead of Joda?

Comment: Thanks @andrewjames for refreshing my memory. I've updated the answer.

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, rather than using Joda-Time, I would suggest using he back-port of *java.time* available in [ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Having nearly the same API makes it trivial to eventually switch to the built-in *java.time*.